# regarding to connection with sql server and netbeans

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, netbeans, tcp

Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\dbo:1433;databaseName=inv using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".)

[image]

Comment: After local host replace '\ ' with '/' and try...check username and password  Or it is a problem of Jar

Comment: still it same problem

Comment: one more option u can try ..you can resolve the problem by going into the SQL server configuration manager and adding port 1433 into the All IP Addresses section